# close() was never explicitly called on database, DatabasedObjectNotClosed Exception?

Tags: android, sqlite, exception

I am getting following error even I have closed all instances as soon as I finish calling them:

```
 close() was never explicitly called on database '/data/data/com.click4tab.fragmentvogella/databases/NewOrderDB' 

 android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
```

I was not getting this error until I defined this method.

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.item1:
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Button one pressed",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // write data on server
            TestAdapter mDbHelper = new TestAdapter(this);

            mDbHelper.createDatabase();
            mDbHelper.open();

            try {
                mDbHelper.writeUnwrittenNetOrder();
                mDbHelper.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
                               break;
```

And the definition to writeUnwrittenNetOrder:

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    StringBuffer strbuf = new StringBuffer();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", "add_NetOrderID"));

    for (mCur.moveToFirst(); !mCur.isAfterLast(); mCur.moveToNext()) {

        String sql3 = "INSERT into NetOrderID (StoreID, Date, SalesManID, NetOrderID) VALUES ("
                + mCur.getString(0)
                + ", "
                + mCur.getString(1)
                + ", "
                + mCur.getString(2) + ", " + mCur.getString(3) + ");";
         if((mCur.isLast())){
        strbuf.append(sql3);
         }
         else {
             strbuf.append(sql3 + "#");
         }
        // String sql3 =
        // "INSERT into NetOrderID (StoreID, SalesManID, NetOrderID) VALUES (1,1,80)";
        // sqlQueries.add(sql3);
        Log.e("sql", strbuf.toString());


    }


    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("query", strbuf.toString()));
    Log.e("param","param added");

    new SyncWithServer();
    // send params
    SyncWithServer.setParams(params);
    Log.e("param","param set");

    // return arraylist
}
```

Where should I close the mDbHelper to avoid this error, well this error is coming up in Logcat while the database is getting successfully written and the Application is not crashing.

Comment: ducli http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940308/im-getting-a-database-object-not-closed-exception-in-sqlite-android-but-im

Answer (score 1):

The error message says you did not close database **or cursor**. Did you close all of them as well (`mCur` object)?

Comment: I never closed a cursor, only used to close database and it was working fine.

Comment: Where exactly should I close cursor?

Comment: As soon as you're done using it. From first glance, probably right before `params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("query", strbuf.toString()));`

Comment: just like Jochem said - close it as soon as you do not need it anymore. Which means after all DB read/write operations are done. This is the case - just like in the dup question provided by jenuine. And (quote from answer to that question): "you can create a `ContentProvider`, use an `SQLiteOpenHelper` and not worry about closing it at all". Maybe this is a solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

Alex makes a good point.

And also (but I don't think that's what's causing the error right now): I think it is better to take the `mDbHelper.close()` statement out of the try/catch, or put it in a `finally` clause. Because currently, when `writeUnwrittenNetOrder` throws an exception, `mDbHelper.close()` will never be called. Something comparable will yields for when you're adding the cursor close method as Alex suggested: this should also happen regardless of exceptions that occur between open and close.

Comment: I placed it inside finally and still its producing same output :(

Comment: Yeah, like I said, I don't think it is the problem in this case. I think you should try Alex' solution for that.

Comment: Where should I close the cursor?

Comment: As soon as you're done using it. From first glance, probably right before params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("query", strbuf.toString()));

Comment: Still the same, I don't understand where it needs to be closed :-/