# Closing database or cursor in Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

When do we need to close database or cursors to avoid errors like this:

```
android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException
```

Could anyone provide brief example about closing database or cursors?
There isn't any reliable source of information, even on `android developers` I can't find any specific rule how to handle closing db or cursor.

---

And the next issue is that the problem occurs only in Android 2.3.3, in 4.1.2 LogCat doesn't seem to show anything.

Comment: Answer at this Question might help building an understanding. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940308/im-getting-a-database-object-not-closed-exception-in-sqlite-android-but-im

Comment: check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557154/android-sqlite-db-when-to-close

Comment: Every person has different solution and own idea, but I can't see there any precise answer to my question.

Comment: There isn't enough information to go by.  Post some of your relavant code.

Comment: I'm sure, there is. I'm asking about general matter, not my particular case.