# Error database not open

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Hey I'm trying to insert data in the SQLite database, but everytime I try to insert the logcat shows the error. THe error ir shown on a service that gets the calllog data and insert in the DB.

Error:

> 02-15 17:07:51.658: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25392): java.lang.IllegalStateException: database not open

And the error is in this line of the Service class:

> db.insert(DataHandlerDB.TABLE_NAME_2, null, values);

**Here is the service:**

```
public class TheService extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = "TheService";
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "TheService";
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    class TheContentObserver extends ContentObserver {

        public TheContentObserver(Handler h) {

            super(h);
            OpenHelper helper = new OpenHelper(getApplicationContext());
            SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();

        }

        @Override
        public boolean deliverSelfNotifications() {

            return true;

        }

        @Override
        public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {

            super.onChange(selfChange);
            searchInsert();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {

        return null;

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        db = DataHandlerDB.createDB(this);
        registerContentObservers();

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){

        db.close();

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {

    }

    private void searchInsert() {

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,
                android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC ");

        int numberColumnId = cursor
                .getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
        int durationId = cursor
                .getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
        int contactNameId = cursor
                .getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME);
        int numTypeId = cursor
                .getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NUMBER_TYPE);
        int callTypeId = cursor
                .getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.TYPE);

        Date dt = new Date();
        int hours = dt.getHours();
        int minutes = dt.getMinutes();
        int seconds = dt.getSeconds();
        String currTime = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yyyy");
        Date date = new Date();

        cursor.moveToFirst();

        String contactNumber = cursor.getString(numberColumnId);
        String contactName = (null == cursor.getString(contactNameId) ? ""
                : cursor.getString(contactNameId));
        String duration = cursor.getString(durationId);
        String numType = cursor.getString(numTypeId);
        String callType = cursor.getString(callTypeId);

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put("contact_id", 1);
        values.put("contact_name", contactName);
        values.put("number_type", numType);
        values.put("contact_number", contactNumber);
        values.put("duration", duration);
        values.put("date", dateFormat.format(date));
        values.put("current_time", currTime);
        values.put("cont", 1);
        values.put("type", callType);

        if (!db.isOpen()) {
            getApplicationContext().openOrCreateDatabase(
                    "/data/data/com.my_app/databases/mydb.db",
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE, null);
        }
        db.insert(DataHandlerDB.TABLE_NAME_2, null, values);
        cursor.close();


    }

    public void registerContentObservers() {

        this.getApplicationContext()
                .getContentResolver()
                .registerContentObserver(
                        android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, true,
                        new TheContentObserver(handler));

    }

}
```

**And here is the DataHandlerDB Class:**

```
public class DataHandlerDB {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mydb.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    protected static final String TABLE_NAME = "table1";
    protected static final String TABLE_NAME_2 = "table2";
    protected String TAG = "DataHandlerDB";

//create the DB     
    public static SQLiteDatabase createDB(Context ctx) {
        OpenHelper helper = new OpenHelper(ctx);
        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        helper.onOpen(db);
        db.close();
        return db;
    }
public static class OpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        private final Context mContext;

        OpenHelper(Context context) {

            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            this.mContext = context;

        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

            String[] sql = mContext.getString(R.string.ApplicationDatabase_OnCreate).split("\n");

            db.beginTransaction();

            try{
                execMultipleSQL(db, sql);
                db.setTransactionSuccessful();
            } catch (SQLException e) {

                Log.e("Error creating tables and debug data", e.toString());
                throw e;

            } finally {
                db.endTransaction();

            }
        }

        private void execMultipleSQL(SQLiteDatabase db, String[] sql) {

            for(String s : sql){

                if(s.trim().length() > 0){

                    db.execSQL(s);
                }
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            /*Log.w("Application Database",
                    "Upgrading database, this will drop tables and recreate.");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
            onCreate(db);*/
        }

        @Override 
        public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db){

            super.onOpen(db);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: @psyhclo First you should change what Dan Breslau mentions. There are also some other things I would change. I have to take a look tomorrow. Did you try this already?

Comment: @Beasly I'm gonna try it now.

Comment: I assume it works now. But the `OpenHelper` should be called just in your `DataHandlerDB`

Comment: @Beasly How to call only on the DataHandlerDB if I need to open the DB on the activity, and for that the only solution I found was instatiate the helper and db objects so I can open the database on the activity. Do you have another solution for this problem?? Thanks man!! =)

Comment: Your mehtods in DataHandlerDB are static so just implement e.g. a insert method with the needed parameters. Then call in your activity `DataHanderDB.insert(...);`

Comment: @Beasly but I'm using the native method insert. so I can use with ContentValues, got it??

Comment: To be honest. No ;) Anyway do it like you think it works for you. Generally you should separate the logic from the presentation if you can. The MVC pattern.

Comment: @Beasly I'm gonna try that. I'm gonna think in a solution for that. Thanks for the tips and help in general!! =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't you want this code

```
 if (!db.isOpen()) {
        getApplicationContext().openOrCreateDatabase(
                "/data/data/com.my_app/databases/mydb.db",
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE, null);
 }
```

to be:

```
 if (!db.isOpen()) {
    db = getApplicationContext().openOrCreateDatabase(
                "/data/data/com.my_app/databases/mydb.db",
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE, null);
 }
```

?

Also, in the function

```
    public TheContentObserver(Handler h) {
        super(h);
        OpenHelper helper = new OpenHelper(getApplicationContext());
        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    }
```

`helper` and `db` are local variables, not class members. This means that the database that you open here is not used for anything, anywhere.